# Blazor - .NET 8 - Can't load styles.css from external assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

Is there a problem with .NET 8 and Blazor or just a problem with my project?  I have a common assembly so I can build as either Maui or Web Assembly.  I've done this before.  I have a .NET 6 and .NET 7 projects, set up the same way, where it's all working as expected.

So, I think it's all set up ok:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/CommonAssembly/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" /> <!-- Loads -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/CommonAssembly/css/app.css" /> <!-- Loads -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CommonAssembly.styles.css" /> <!-- Does not load -->
```

The styles.css file about does not load.

The main layout and the individual views are also in CommonAssembly.  These also load.

But when the app launches and it tries to load:

```
https://0.0.0.0/CommonAssembly.styles.css
```

The file is not found and can't be loaded.

The external assembly is registered in my routes:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(MauiProgram).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] {typeof(MainLayout).Assembly}">
```

Has anyone come across this with .NET 8?  Can anyone suggest something I can try?

Comment: Can you please add a [mre] somewhere like github?

Comment: According to the [reference about sharing assets across web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-8.0#share-web-ui-razor-components-code-and-static-assets) and native clients using a Razor class library (RCL), if we want to load static files from RCL in the main blazor app, we should refer the file like `_content/SharedLibrary/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`.  Pls correct me if I misunderstood your issue and provide a minimal sample.

Comment: If you need something from RCL you need to start the path with `_content`. Try to publish the app with `dotnet publish` and you will see what files are at your disposal (for example `_content` folder in your `wwwroot`).

Comment: @Alamakanambra Thanks.  I'm not looking to load something from the wwwroot.  I'm trying to load the isolated css generated in the page.razor.css files.

Comment: Every local file you are able to load is published to `wwwroot` (on publish, not on build). While developing the files from RCLs and scoped csss are linked (not actually copied to `wwwroot`). My advice to you is publishing the app so you can see exactly the path to files you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was assuming the isolated css would be loaded from the common assembly.  When the project builds, it builds the isolated CSS into the main assembly so I had to replace:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CommonAssembly.styles.css" />
```

With:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MainAssembly.styles.css" />
```